# Apps crash due to crashlytics build errors on apache ant

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, crashlytics

We have configured Crashlytics for our android projects. We have set up the eclipse plugin for dev machines and we are trying to use the ant modules for our build machines.
We have followed the instructions as per the website but unfortunately when we run the signed APK release build on devices the apps crash and the logcat shows

```
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     |  | 
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     |  |
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     |  |
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .   \ |  | /
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .    \    /
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     \  /
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .      \/
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): This app relies on Crashlytics. Configure your build environment here: 
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): https://crashlytics.com/register/[key value]/android/pkgname  //Vrashabh// Key value has been hidden to send to crashlytics
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .      /\
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     /  \
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .    /    \
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .   / |  | \
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     |  |
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     |  |
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .     |  |
06-13 15:57:16.131: E/Crashlytics(21660): .
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): Process: com.pengala.client, PID: 21660
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pengala.client/com.pengala.client.SplashActivity}: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): This app relies on Crashlytics. Configure your build environment here: 
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): https://crashlytics.com/register/[key value]/android/pkgname  //Vrashabh// Key value has been hidden to send to crashlytics
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): Caused by: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): This app relies on Crashlytics. Configure your build environment here: 
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): https://crashlytics.com/register/[key value]/android/pkgname  //Vrashabh// Key value has been hidden to send to crashlytics
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.crashlytics.android.d.a(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.crashlytics.android.d.d(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.crashlytics.android.internal.cg.b(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ck.d(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.crashlytics.android.internal.cg.b(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ck.a(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.crashlytics.android.d.a(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.pengala.client.SplashActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-13 15:57:16.141: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    ... 11 more
```

What additional steps are we missing?

Steps done:

```
1.) Eclipse plugin added, manifest has crashlytics API key
2.) Crashlytics ant folder copied to build machine and imported by custom_rules.xml
```

We have followed the instructions mentioned here: 
http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/203395-ant

but to no avail

**Please note that the app when built with eclipse works without any errors.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics here. Add the import file for ﻿crashlytics_build.xml into your build.xml above a line similar to this:

```
﻿<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" /
```

which will ensure that Crashlytics tasks are imported before the build.

Comment: I've got the same error when using gradle is there any workaround for that?

Comment: whats about android studio? my app was working fine when compiled from windows machine but when i compile it in mac it crashes with same exception.